# Can't create trait variations for constraints

Tags: ios, cocoa, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

Hi I'm having a problem adding constraints that are installed based on size classes. I'd like to have certain constraints be installed on compact vertical traits.

I have enabled Use Trait Variations in File Inspector, buy I still cannot see the little plus button next to Installed for adding them.

[image: File Inspector settings]

[image]